# ArrayList constructor accepting Collection

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a simple question.

Lets say we have a `Map`, for example a `Map<String, Object>`

I want a method that returns a list of all values inside the `Map`.

The approach i use is the following:

1. I create a `List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();`
2. Get an `iterator` from the value set of the `Map`.
3. For each element inside the `iterator i` put a reference in the `myList` list.
4. Return the list
5. ...later for each element i use i wrap it inside a `synchronized` block because the list contains references.

Now i am woring about using an easier apporach. The one i mean is the following:

```
return new ArrayList(myMap.values());
```

As you see in this case i simply use the constructor of the `List` interface which accepts a Collection.

And finally my question is:

**If i use the second approach do i still get references or it copies the value objects that are inside the map?**

Answer (score 3):

In both cases you will get "shallow" copy of collecion, so both arrays will keep references to the same objects.

Answer (score 2):

`return new ArrayList(myMap.values())` will return an ArrayList containing the references of the original values of the Map. No copies of the values instances are created.

Note that if your Map contains duplicate values (i.e. values that are equal to each other), your ArrayList will also contain duplicate values. If you want to eliminate the duplicates, you should create a Set of the values instead of a List.

Answer (score 2):

In either case you'll get a copy of the reference (so called *"shallow copy"*).

There is no deep-copying (creating a completely new object with meaningfully equivalent fields -- also deep-copied) involved.